# How can i set the home page in Edge Chromium with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge

I wrote a script to update the new Edge Chromium browser. And now I'm looking for a way to set the home page (first page to open when Edge starts) using Powershell.

Can someone help me?

Comment: List what you have tried and any notes / errors.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I wrote you a comment on your message with all the things I tried. And sorry but your solution is not working for me. (Edge Version: 84.0.522.52)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the homepage of Edge Chromium by editing the registry with Powershell.

We need to set two settings in Edge Chromium:

1. [RestoreOnStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#restoreonstartup): **Action to take on startup**

If you want to open Edge Chromium with new page with a url, then you should set this registry like below:

- Path: SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge
- Value Name: RestoreOnStartup
- Value Type: REG_DWORD
- Value Data: 0x00000004

Powershell Script:

```
$registryPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge'

$name = 'RestoreOnStartup'

$value = 0x00000004

IF(!(Test-Path $registryPath))

  {

    New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null

    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null}

 ELSE {

    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null}
```

[image]

2. [RestoreOnStartupURLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#restoreonstartupurls): **Sites to open when the browser starts**

This registry setting is used to set the url of the homepage. You should set it like below:

- Path: SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\Recommended\RestoreOnStartupURLs
- Value Name: 1, 2, 3, ...
- Value Type: list of REG_SZ
- Value Data: the url you want to set as homepage

Powershell Script:

```
New-Item -Path HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge -Name RestoreOnStartupURLs –Force

$path = 'HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\RestoreOnStartupURLs'

$name = '1'

$value = 'https://www.homepage.com'

Set-Itemproperty -Path $path -Name $name -Value $value
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, i tried your code but sadly it didn't work. I tried it with diffrent users, in HKCU and HKLM but edge always says in edge://policy This policy is blocked: The value is ignored.I also read that this is a bug in Edge. It'll be fixed in future versions. Could this be correct?

Comment: It works for me and my Edge version is the same as yours so it's strange that it doesn't work for you. Where do you find that it's a bug of Edge? If you found it from official site, I think you can trust it and wait for the fix in future versions.

Comment: I don't remember but I think I found it on the official Microsoft forum. I tried it now with GPOs but i get the same result.

Comment: This method will work only if your system is part of Active Directory. If the system is not joined to an AD, the policy which you set via regedit or gcpedit it will be ignored. This is applicable for both Edge and Chrome as both are running on chromium project. You can navigate to the URL edge://policy in Edge and chrome://policy in google chrome to see the accepted policy. if system is not in AD, the policy RestoreOnStartupURLs status will be "Error and Ignored"